# iOS App display error: Black rectangle artifact beside button

Tags: autolayout, swift4, ios13, xcode11, artifacts

After updating to iOS 13, a black rectangle appears next to a button on the login screen of my app. I'm told it appears for users running iOS 12 as well. This is the artifact:

[image: first].

The app was written in Swift 4 using Xcode 11. The artifact appears to be cutting off the normal width of the login button, as if the internal padding was rendered outside the border, so the button looks lopsided.

This is what the login view looks like in Xcode:
[image: This]

Here is the document outline for the login view:

[image: Here]

Here are the attribute settings for the Login button (note: the background is an image asset):

[image: Here]

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HIGdJ.png) are the constraints on the button. I notice there are two identical constraints for aligning horizontally in the parent container- could that cause this?

If I install the app directly using Xcode the artifact does not appear, even if I don't make any changes. However, every employee downloads the IPA from an internal app store and they see it. Can anyone suggest a solution?

Comment: You have provided no information at all about how that button is drawn.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know what you're asking for. It is a standard UIButton from the library. Where can I find the code concerning drawing you're asking about?

Comment: A standard button doesn’t have a rounded rect border and a gray gradient in the middle. All of that is being drawn somehow. How?

Comment: My apologies; it turns out the background image of the button is loaded from a photo asset. You can see it in the attributes panel in the Background option.

Comment: Yes, I see... What other constraints are there on the Login button? It seems like something is shifting the background to the right.

Comment: I updated the post to include the constraints on the login button.

Comment: Your constraints look way overdetermined. You have two align center Xs. You have an align center Y and two top constraints. Do you get no error message in the Console about this?

Comment: And what about the View Debugger? Do you get no exclamation marks?

Comment: No, there were no errors in either the console or view debugger. Removing the duplicate constraint had no effect. However, removing the background image did work. I'm opting to edit the appearance of the button with code instead of using the image now.